# deleteActiveSheet() works to delete multiple sheets, but results only show when I reload browser window

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the script deleteAllCreatedSheets() below to delete 6 sheets in the current spreadsheet. This works correctly, however, after running the script, some of the sheets still show as present until I reload the browser page (F5). This wouldn't be an issue - but every time I reload the browser page, the script editor closes, making it quite a process to run a few scripts during testing! Any ideas?

```
function deleteBankStatement_(stname) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(stname);
  if(!sh) {
    return;
  }
  ss.setActiveSheet(sh);
  ss.deleteActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function deleteAllCreatedSheets() {
  deleteBankStatement_("p-071026363");
  deleteBankStatement_("p-076324478");
  deleteBankStatement_("p-275106284");
  deleteBankStatement_("p-653857497");
  deleteBankStatement_("PettyCash");
  deleteBankStatement_("LCPettyCash");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do in this case, is open the spreadsheet twice, once in each of two browser tabs. From one of the spreadsheets, you could open the Script Editor to run your tests, and in the other spreadsheet, you can do your refreshes.

Related to this, if you'd like the Apps Script team to look into whether it's possible to have the deleted sheets always update in the Spreadsheets UI without having to refresh, you can enter a feature request for that in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: That'd work around the problem, but it's not a solution. The problem here is inconsistent results upon running the script - sometimes the deleted sheets disappear, sometimes they don't, sometimes some of them do...

Comment: I agree. Please do add this to the Apps Script issue tracker, if you haven't already, and we'll have the team take a look. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list